# Mapping Diseases on USA map

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I'm looking to plot a limited set of data for Ebola diseases on USA map using ggplot2 and maps.

The parameters are State and Ebola Infected (yes/no)

States containing the virus are the following:

```
Texas Yes
Newyork Yes
```

These states are to be colored in Red and other states in the country are to be in green.

I'm not sure how to code this and any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code that I could build using other thread on stackoverflow

```
library(ggplot2);
library(maps);
library(plyr);
library(mapproj);
ebolad = read.csv('/usa.csv');
#a data set including the state name and whether it is effected or not (yes/no)
colClasses = c('character', 'character', 'numeric')[[2]];
names(ebolad) = c('col', 'region', 'infected');
ebolad$region  = tolower(ebolad$region);
us_state_map = map_data('state');
map_data = merge(ebolad, us_state_map, by = 'region'); 
map_data = arrange(map_data, order);
ggplot(map_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=infected)) +
  geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2) +
  scale_fill_brewer('States affected with EBOLA Virus in USA', palette = 'PuRd') +
  coord_map();
```

Could someone help me with improving the plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a manual scale for `fill` instead. That is replace `scale_fill_brewer(...)` by

```
scale_fill_manual('States affected with EBOLA Virus in USA', values=c("green","red"))
```

This does not give the most beautiful green and red, though. But you can use hex codes to define arbitrary colours, for instance `values=c("#4daf4a","#e41a1c")`.

Which value for `infected` is coloured red may depend on the details of your data. If the not infected states should be coloured green, simply use `values=c("red","green")` to switch the colours.

If your problem is related to the file `usa.csv`, it is difficult to help without having the file. I produced the data by the following commands:

```
ebolad<-data.frame(region=state.name,infected="no",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ebolad[ebolad$region %in% c("Texas","New York"),"infected"] <- "yes"
```

Then, using your code with the change mentioned before, I get a decent plot.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my query.

Here is the link to the file" usa.csv" : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kPaofcAVWG_ViajHYecUKFjK3D6MQ0acDdVhRnxJWfA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have used your code to read the file and it works for me. Depending on where you store `usa.csv` and what your working directory is, you may have to remove the `/` from the file name. Do you manage to produce a plot using `scale_fill_manual`? If not, do you get any error messages?

Comment: Yes I've used the following command and the plot looks much better
scale_fill_manual('States affected with EBOLA Virus in USA', values=c("#4daf4a","#e41a1c"))

Thanks a lot for your inputs @Stibu

Comment: how is it possible to mark the names of states on the map? I'm trying to name the infected states and leave the rest

Comment: I used the below 'code' and was able to generate a map with all the state name abbreviations

states <- data.frame(state.center, state.abb)
ggplot(map_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=infected)) +
  geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2) +
  geom_text(data = states, aes(x = x, y = y, label = state.abb, group = NULL), size = 4)+
  scale_fill_manual('States affected with EBOLA Virus in USA', values=c("green4","red3")) +
    coord_map(project="globular") +
  theme_grey();

Answer (score 0):

```
  #Code to map USA states affected with Ebola Virus
    #import the following libraries
    library(ggplot2);
    library(maps);
    library(plyr);
    #begin of code
    # read the csv file containing the ebola data for usa (important: replace the directory path)
    ebolad = read.csv('usa.csv');
    colClasses = c('character', 'character', 'numeric')[[2]];
    names(ebolad) = c('col', 'region', 'infected');
    ebolad$region  = tolower(ebolad$region);
    # import the usa state data into local dataset
    us_state_map = map_data('state');
    # merge ebola data set and usa maps data set
    map_data = merge(ebolad, us_state_map, by = 'region'); 
    map_data = arrange(map_data, order);
    # storing the data of abbreviated state names to display on the final map
    states <- data.frame(state.center, state.abb)
    # code to plot the map with state names and colors to distinguish the infected states vs uninfected states
    ggplot(map_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +
    geom_polygon(aes(fill=infected)) +
    geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2) +
    xlab("Longitude") + ylab("Latitude") +
    geom_text(data = states, aes(x = x, y = y, label = state.abb, group = NULL), size = 4)+
    scale_fill_manual('States affected with EBOLA Virus in USA', values=c("green4","red3")) +
    coord_map(project="globular") +
    theme_grey();
    #end of code
```

Comment: Map can be viewed here [link] (https://drive.google.com/a/mst.edu/file/d/0B9PNapMMz8nBbTNwWDd3ZWkyTTA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your question (and answer) are not reproducible and the figure you link to in the comment is unavailable (without first attaining access). Consider the net worth of this in the long run.